# How can I decode f16 to f32 using only the stable standard library?

Tags: floating-point, rust, precision

I need to convert stored half floats (16 bit) to standard 32 bit floats. I currently use the code below, but it relies on libc. I want to use only `std` and it should work on stable Rust.

```
#[inline]
fn decode_f16(half: u16) -> f32 {
    let exp: u16 = half >> 10 & 0x1f;
    let mant: u16 = half & 0x3ff;
    let val: f32 = if exp == 0 {
        ffi::c_ldexpf(mant as f32, -24)
    } else if exp != 31 {
        ffi::c_ldexpf(mant as f32 + 1024f32, exp as isize - 25)
    } else if mant == 0 {
        ::std::f32::INFINITY
    } else {
        ::std::f32::NAN
    };
    if half & 0x8000 != 0 {
        -val
    } else {
        val
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you just use https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.ldexp and wait for it to get stable?

Comment: The crate should work on stable now. In addition the ldexp method is unlikely to get stabilized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just replace `ffi::c_ldexpf(x, y)` with `x * (2.0).powi(y)`. This works on all `u16`s, according to [my exhaustive test](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a1cd50f65134d1df54cf&version=nightly).